# OpenCV color identification

Tags: python, c, opencv, colors

Hi I'm trying to built simple color identifying program. I have taken a image (yellow & pink) with  and convert it in HSV color space. Then used threshold to identify yellow color region. I getting the output (black image). I want yellow region to be filled with while color and rest with black.

---

[image] [image]

---

```
IplImage *imgRead= cvLoadImage("yellow.jpeg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(!imgRead) {
fprintf(stderr, "Error in reading image\n");
exit(1);
}
IplImage *imgHsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgRead),8, 3);
cvCvtColor(imgRead, imgHsv,CV_BGR2HSV);

IplImage *imgThreshold = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgRead),8, 1);
cvInRangeS(imgHsv, cvScalar(25, 80, 80,80), cvScalar(34, 255, 255,255), imgThreshold);
cvShowImage("image",imgThreshold);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

In above code I had calculated HSV value for yellow as 30. (In gimp hsv value for yellow color is 60). In `cvInRangeS`, except for hue value I'm not sure how to specify other values for `cvScalar`.

What values I need to put? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and it worked fine. Perhaps the yellow in your image isn't as yellow as you think.

[image]

**Edit:** The other potential difference is that I'm using OpenCV 2.3. Which version are you using?

**Ok, one more edit:** Have you tried looking at your yellow values? That would give you a definitive answer as to what values you should use in cvInRangeS. Add these two lines after the call to cvCvtColor:

```
uchar* ptr = (uchar*)(imgHsv->imageData);
printf("H: %d, S:%d, V:%d\n", ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2]);
```

For my image, I got:

```
H: 30, S:109, V:255
```

That's why your code worked for me.

Comment: hi, Im using OpenCV 2.1.0.3. Im using ubuntu 1104, 64 bit. In synaptic it shows this as latest version. I think repositories for 64 bit are not updated as regularly as for 32 bit. I inserted the lines, I got values **H: 30, S:255, V:255**

Comment: I just realized you have a fourth value in your scalar. The behavior of that fourth value is probably undefined since it's a 3-channel image. You should change that line to `cvInRangeS(imgHsv, cvScalar(25, 80, 80), cvScalar(34, 255, 255), imgThreshold);`

Comment: ok, i just increased the upper range of threshold more than 255 to 256 (35, 256, 256,256), it worked.  **cvInRangeS(imgHsv, cvScalar(25, 245, 245,0), cvScalar(35, 256, 256,256), imgThreshold);**. I should have noticed the comments for **cvInRangeS /* dst(idx) = lower <= src(idx) < upper */**

Comment: The documentation for cvInRangeS contradicts itself. In the description it says the upper boundary is inclusive but the function shows it's *less than* instead of *less than or equal to*. I believe that it is inclusive. I think your change works because you changed the fourth value to zero. But I still suggest removing the fourth value.

Comment: I kept fourth value to non-zero. `cvInRangeS(imgHsv, cvScalar(25, 245, 245,245), cvScalar(35, 255, 255,255), imgThreshold);`. It didnot worked. And values more than upper range works fine `cvInRangeS(imgHsv, cvScalar(25, 245, 245,245), cvScalar(35, 256, 256,256), imgThreshold);`

Comment: The fourth value is probably looking at the H value of the next pixel. You shouldn't use a four-value scalar with a 3-channel image. Try `cvInRangeS(imgHsv, cvScalar(25, 80, 80), cvScalar(34, 255, 255), imgThreshold);` and let us know if it works.

Comment: It gives me error `too few arguments to function `. Probably because i'm writing in C not C++. Also, cvScalar defines default value to 0. `CV_INLINE  CvScalar cvScalar( double val0, double val1 CV_DEFAULT(0),double val2 CV_DEFAULT(0), double val3 CV_DEFAULT(0))`

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem you are having is due to the scaling of the HSV data to fit in 8-bits. Normally, as I'm sure you noticed from using GIMP that HSV scales are as follows:

> ```
> H -> [0, 360]
> S -> [0, 100]
> V -> [0, 100]
> ```

But, OpenCV remaps these values as follows:

> ```
> (H / 2) -> [0, 180] (so that the H values can be stored in 8-bits)
> S       -> [0, 255]
> V       -> [0, 255]
> ```

This is why your calculated Hue value is 30 instead of 60. So, to filter out all colors except for yellow your `cvInRangeS` call would look something like this:

```
cvInRangeS(imgHsv, cvScalar(25, 245, 245, 0), cvScalar(35, 255, 255, 255), imgThreshold);
```

The fourth channel is unused for HSV. This call would give you 10-counts of noise in your color detector threshold for each dimension.

As mentioned by, SSteve your threshold should work, but you may need to expand your threshold boundaries to capture the yellow-ish color in your image.

Hope that helps!